# Java Generics: Instantiating arrays with parameterized types: illegal?

Tags: java, arrays, generics, compiler-construction, type-erasure

I must be confused here.

I read everywhere that in generics arrays of parametrized types are illegal.

Example from [AngelikaLanger](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ParameterizedTypes.html#How%20can%20I%20work%20around%20the%20restriction%20that%20there%20are%20no%20arrays%20whose%20component%20type%20is%20a%20concrete%20instantiation%20of%20a):

```
static void test() {  
  Pair<Integer,Integer>[] intPairArr = new Pair<Integer,Integer>[10] ; // error  
  addElements(intPairArr);   
  Pair<Integer,Integer> pair = intPairArr[1];  
  Integer i = pair.getFirst();  
  pair.setSecond(i);  
}
```

Quote from Langer (but everywhere else I read it says the same thing):

> The compiler prohibits creation of arrays whose component type is a
>   concrete parameterized type, like Pair in our
>   example.  We discussed in the preceding entry why is it reasonable
>   that the compiler qualifies a Pair[] as illegal.

So far ok.

But in my code here:

```
private MyEntry<E> [] elements = (MyEntry<E>[])new Object[capacity];
```

I do exactly that, it compiles fine (I use eclipse) but get a class cast exception error (Object can not be cast to MyEntry):

My question is, why does this line compiles in the first place?

I thought that this instantiation is disallowed by the compiler.

What I am doing wrong/differerent here?

**UPDATE:**

On the same page, why am I able to succesfully do:

```
List<E> elements[] = (List<E>[])new LinkedList[capacity];
```

and have **no runtime exceptions**?

**UPDATE:**

Everywhere I have read (mentioned Langer since she's quoted often) it says that this declaration (arrays of parametrized types) is disallowed by compiler.
I can understand what happens after that.
I can't understand why the compiler doesn't report an error.
I am not judging, I am saying everywhere I read, it says this does not compile.
Am I missreading something?

**UPDATE:** 
I saw some comments related to the missing parameter in the `new` part.
This also has **no** issue:

```
List<Entry<KeyType, ValueType>> table[] = (List<Entry<KeyType, ValueType>>[])new LinkedList[capacity];
```

Comment: `LinkedList` implements `List`, so that **downcast** is acceptable; `Object` is not a subclass of `MyEntry`, so that **upcast** raises an error.

Comment: You are doing `new LinkedList[]`: there is **no** type parameter there, so no problems; what you can't do is `new LinkedList<E>[]`. Doing a typed cast has nothing do to with not being able to do the initialization, and because of type erasure `(List<E>[])` at runtime becomes `(List[])`, a valid cast for `new LinkedList[]`.

Comment: @Viruzzo:See update.I can do `<E>` on `new`.

Comment: @downvoter:If it is stupid question then why don't you answer so that I can understand this as well?

Comment: Doing a cast inside `new`? Whatever you are trying to do with that, it's not a valid Java statement.

Comment: @Viruzzo:Yes by bad, it was error in copy-paste.Sorry, I corrected OP

Comment: You are still missing the point: doing a cast there has **no effect** on the new operation; it is done *after* the new has been executed.

Comment: @Viruzzo:My main confusion is that the 3rd example should not even compile if I understand Langer's quote.This is my main problem.Why does it compile.I see it in contradiction with Langer's quote.

Comment: Casts are done at runtime, so that one doesn't prevent compilation; in any case, Langer doesn't use casts in her example, it's something you added.

Answer (score 2):

In your first example, there's no problem with the instantiation - here's exactly what you're creating:

```
new Object[capacity]
```

Perfectly legal.  You do however get a runtime exception when you attempt to cast, because an array of `Object` is not an array of `MyEntry<E>`.  You might have a point that the *cast* or *declaration* could be rejected by the compiler, if these generically-parameterised arrays can't exist, though this depends what order erasure kicks in.  In any case, the instantiation itself is fine.

In the second example, you're creating a non-generic array of `LinkedList`.  You then assign it to a genericised reference, which at runtime will have been erased to just a `List[]`.  This works fine (because rightly or wrongly, arrays are covariant).

I'm not sure why you were expecting a runtime exception; it's not much different to calling, say

```
List<E> = new LinkedList();
```

You would get some unchecked warnings, but nothing that would stop the code compiling or running.

Comment: For the first example everywhere I have read (mentioned Langer since she's quoted often) it says that this declaration is dissallowed by compiler.I can understand what happens after that.I can't understand why the compiler doesn't report an error.I am not judging, I am saying everywhere I read it says this does not compile.Am I missreading something?

Comment: My point was that nowhere are you *creating generic arrays* - you're creating non-generic arrays, and then later trying to cast them to something which may or may not succeed.  If your first example was `private MyEntry<E>[] elements = new MyEntry<E>[capacity];` it would fail to compile with a "generic array creation" error - I hope you can see why this is different to what you *actually* have.

Comment: On the other hand, if you changed the line to `MyEntry<E>[] elements = new MyEntry[capacity];` then creating the array would work (as it's now non-generic), *and* the cast should work, so this would function roughly as you might expect.  Going back to the Langer quote, the important part is that she mentions creation of arrays whose component type is a **concrete parameterized type**.  `Object` is not parameterised, and `MyEntry` is a raw type, so these both work.  `MyEntry<E>` is a concrete parameterised type, so array creation with this would fail.

Answer (score 1):

Because `LinkedList` is an instance of `List`.
But `Object` is **NOT** an instance of `MyEntry`.
Also compiler don't check can one object be cast to another or not. Because it is runtime operation.

You should use:

```
private MyEntry<E> [] elements = new MyEntry [capacity];
```

Or:

```
class SomeOtherEntry extends MyEntry {}

private MyEntry<E> [] elements = new SomeOtherEntry [capacity];
```

But not:

```
class SomeOtherEntry extends MyEntry {}

private SomeOtherEntry <E> [] elements = new MyEntry [capacity];
```

**UPDATE:**

```
List<Entry<KeyType, ValueType>> [] table = (List<Entry<KeyType,ValueType>> []) new Linked[capacity];
```

Answer (score 1):

You have completely misunderstood whatever you have read. There is absolutely nothing wrong with having the *type* that is an array of a parameterized type: `MyEntry<E>[]` or `HashMap<String,Integer>[][]` or whatever. You can have variables of such types all you want, and use them anywhere a type can be used.

However, with array creation, you cannot do something like `new MyEntry<E>[...]`. It is not allowed by the language (for type safety reasons we will not go into here), so it is a compile error.

The best solution is either `new MyEntry[]` (array of raw type) or `new MyEntry<?>[]` (array of wildcard type); either one is allowed by the language. Both of them will require you to do an explicit cast back to `MyEntry<E>[]`.

Since you ask about your code examples, your first example is syntactically correct (there is nothing wrong with `new Object[...]`, and it is syntactically okay to cast to `MyEntry<E>[]`), so there is no compile error. However, the runtime check of the cast fails at runtime, because the object's actual type `Object[]` is not a subtype of `MyEntry[]`.

The second code example is also syntactically correct, and plus the runtime check of the cast succeeds (`LinkedList[]` *is* a subtype of `List[]`).

Comment: What about the 3rd example?Also your second para "However, with array creation, ...." with the analysis of my code examples seem to me inconsistent.There is something I don't get I guess....

Comment: @user384706: the third example is also fine. The only difference between the second and third examples is the type in the cast. The types in both cases are valid. I don't get what you're trying to demonstrate

Comment: @user384706: what don't you get about my analysis?

Comment: :I am not trying to demonstrate anything.Only to understand this.I think I see where I was confused.This is allowed by compiler:`Pair<Integer,Integer>[] intPairArr` but this is not: `new Pair<Integer,Integer>[10] ;`.But this is allowed `new Pair[10] ;`.Right. So the problem is not instantiating the array but when explitily paramerizing `new`.I didn't realize this before

Comment: @user384706: `Pair<Integer,Integer>[] intPairArr;` does not instantiate anything. It just declares a variable of that reference type. `new Pair<Integer,Integer>[10]` is the array creation expression. In array creation, the component type cannot be parameterized, except with `?`.

Answer (score 0):

Built-in Java List classes actually use a work-around whenever you use the 
`<T> T[] toArray(T[] a)` method. If we take a closer look at the code, if you supply an array that's smaller than required, the method actually creates a new array of the type parameter.

Let's see the code: https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/f4d80957e89a19a29bb9f9807d2a28351ed7f7df/src/share/classes/java/util/LinkedList.java#L1085

```
public <T> T[] toArray(T[] a) {
   if (a.length < size)
      a = (T[])java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(a.getClass().getComponentType(), size);
    ...
}
```